# I want to create navigation bar for my application

Tags: html, css, menu, navigation

I want to achieve something like this..

[image: Here is how it should look]

note: dynamically more child (i.e second and third) elements will be added. 'first' which is root element appears only once.
Please suggest me how I can do it?additionally it should be collapsible.

Comment: Please add what you did and and place your some code.

Comment: Any specific reason for using 'div' only? This can be better achieved with 'ul' 'li' structure.

Comment: @zipkundan I have already implement this part and our client have requested for this feature.so it is anyway i can incorporate it with my existing code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this link is useful to you

http://mackpexton.com/projects/TreeMenu/index.htm

Answer (score 0):

Please  add some code of your program 
some example menu

```css
<style>
#header {
    background-color:black;
    color:white;
    text-align:center;
    padding:5px;
}
#nav {
    line-height:30px;
    background-color:#eeeeee;
    height:300px;
    width:100px;
    float:left;
    padding:5px;       
}
#section {
    width:350px;
    float:left;
    padding:10px;    
}
#footer {
    background-color:black;
    color:white;
    clear:both;
    text-align:center;
   padding:5px;    
}
</style>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

<div id="header">
<h1>City Gallery</h1>
</div>

<div id="nav">
London<br>
Paris<br>
Tokyo
</div>

<div id="section">
<h2>London</h2>
<p>asd</p>
<p>type text </p>
</div>

  

</body>
</html>
```